# Is it possible to trigger shell command-line execution via an on-chain transaction?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, substrate, polkadot

I want to design an application to buy and sell machine learning models as if they were commodities.But other nodes need to agree whether the model is consistent with the uploader's description.So I'm wondering if it's possible to trigger the execution of shell commands down the chain.

Comment: Check this out and let us know what you find https://substrate.dev/recipes/off-chain-workers/index.html

Comment: On Stack Ovetflow, questions should contain enough information so that anyone can reproduce the error on their own. Just showing an error message is insufficient. Please edit the question to explain fully what you're working with. It might help to read: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask